# My macbook air is very loud!

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

My MacBook Air's fan is spinning rapidly even though there are hardly any programs running. A couple of weeks ago my mum accidentally spilled water on it and we had to take it to get fixed. After it had been fixed, everything was working fine but my laptop has been very noisy ever since. Even when there are no programs running. How do I stop my laptop from being so loud?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your power adapter and turn the machine off. Press and hold control+option+shift+power buttons for 5 seconds. This resets the System Management controller, which is in charge of power flow through your machine and also things like the speed of your fan.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3964

If that does not help, the computer may still be damaged. Where did you have it repaired?